# MiNiFi - NiFi unable to communicate with host:port connection timed out

Tags: apache-nifi

I am running MiNiFi in a windows server which is behind my company's firewall. My NiFi is running on Hortonworks cluster (3 nodes ex:sj46,sj47,sj48).

I am trying to send data from the MiNiFi to NiFi.

- MiNiFi version: 0.4
- NiFi version: 1.5

In MiNiFi, i have ListFile processor, FetchFile processor and RemoteProcessGroup.

**RemoteProcessGroup:**

- URL:
  https://sjxx46.xxx:6689/nifi,https://sjxx47.xxx:6689/nifi,https://sjxx48.xxx:6689/nifi
- TransportProtocol: HTTP

**NiFi.properties:**

```
nifi.remote.input.host=
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec
nifi.remote.input.secure=True
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=6698

nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=6699
nifi.web.http.port=
nifi.web.https.host=sj46.xxxx
nifi.web.https.port=6689
```

**MiNiFi config.yml**

```
MiNiFi Config Version: 3
Flow Controller:
  name: min2510
  comment: ''
Core Properties:
  flow controller graceful shutdown period: 10 sec
  flow service write delay interval: 500 ms
  administrative yield duration: 30 sec
  bored yield duration: 10 millis
  max concurrent threads: 1
  variable registry properties: ''
FlowFile Repository:
  partitions: 256
  checkpoint interval: 2 mins
  always sync: false
  Swap:
    threshold: 20000
    in period: 5 sec
    in threads: 1
    out period: 5 sec
    out threads: 4
Content Repository:
  content claim max appendable size: 10 MB
  content claim max flow files: 100
  always sync: false
Provenance Repository:
  provenance rollover time: 1 min
  implementation: org.apache.nifi.provenance.MiNiFiPersistentProvenanceRepository
Component Status Repository:
  buffer size: 1440
  snapshot frequency: 1 min
Security Properties:
  keystore: ''
  keystore type: ''
  keystore password: ''
  key password: ''
  truststore: ''
  truststore type: ''
  truststore password: ''
  ssl protocol: ''
  Sensitive Props:
    key:
    algorithm: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
    provider: BC
Processors:
- id: 50420aac-ef66-30ac-0000-000000000000
  name: FetchFile
  class: org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFile
  max concurrent tasks: 1
  scheduling strategy: TIMER_DRIVEN
  scheduling period: 0 sec
  penalization period: 30 sec
  yield period: 1 sec
  run duration nanos: 0
  auto-terminated relationships list:
  - failure
  - not.found
  - permission.denied
  Properties:
    Completion Strategy: None
    File to Fetch: ${absolute.path}/${filename}
    Log level when file not found: ERROR
    Log level when permission denied: ERROR
    Move Conflict Strategy: Rename
    Move Destination Directory:
- id: ae4799d5-073c-3dd6-0000-000000000000
  name: ListFile
  class: org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFile
  max concurrent tasks: 1
  scheduling strategy: TIMER_DRIVEN
  scheduling period: 0 sec
  penalization period: 30 sec
  yield period: 1 sec
  run duration nanos: 0
  auto-terminated relationships list: []
  Properties:
    File Filter: '[^\.].*'
    Ignore Hidden Files: 'true'
    Include File Attributes: 'true'
    Input Directory: C:\minifi to EFT
    Input Directory Location: Local
    Maximum File Age:
    Maximum File Size:
    Minimum File Age: 0 sec
    Minimum File Size: 0 B
    Path Filter:
    Recurse Subdirectories: 'true'
    target-system-timestamp-precision: auto-detect
Controller Services: []
Process Groups: []
Input Ports: []
Output Ports: []
Funnels: []
Connections:
- id: 95dde9e7-96a4-3bea-0000-000000000000
  name: FetchFile/success/eef78a5f-cc55-1d33-0000-0000481921e3
  source id: 50420aac-ef66-30ac-0000-000000000000
  source relationship names:
  - success
  destination id: eef78a5f-cc55-1d33-0000-0000481921e3
  max work queue size: 10000
  max work queue data size: 1 GB
  flowfile expiration: 0 sec
  queue prioritizer class: ''
- id: 2ba13196-5ac6-3966-0000-000000000000
  name: ListFile/success/FetchFile
  source id: ae4799d5-073c-3dd6-0000-000000000000
  source relationship names:
  - success
  destination id: 50420aac-ef66-30ac-0000-000000000000
  max work queue size: 10000
  max work queue data size: 1 GB
  flowfile expiration: 0 sec
  queue prioritizer class: ''
Remote Process Groups:
- id: 6bd4b280-646b-3b93-0000-000000000000
  name: ''
  url: https://sj46.xxxx:6689/nifi
  comment: ''
  timeout: 30 sec
  yield period: 10 sec
  transport protocol: HTTP
  proxy host: ''
  proxy port: ''
  proxy user: ''
  proxy password: ''
  local network interface: ''
  Input Ports:
  - id: eef78a5f-cc55-1d33-0000-0000481921e3
    name: From MiNiFi
    comment: ''
    max concurrent tasks: 1
    use compression: false
  Output Ports: []
NiFi Properties Overrides: {}
```

in the MiNiFi windows server, the ports such as 6688,6689 and 6699 are opened.

but if i try to telnet on MiNiFi and NiFi, it was not established.

**minifi-app.log**

```
2019-03-27 15:50:09,152 WARN [Remote Process Group 6bd4b280-646b-3b93-0000-000000000000 Thread-1] o.a.n.r.util.SiteToSiteRestApiClient Failed to get controller from https://sj46.xxxx:6689/nifi-api due to org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to sj46.xxxx:6689 [sj46.xxxx/x.x.x.x] failed: Connection timed out: connect
2019-03-27 15:50:09,160 WARN [Remote Process Group 6bd4b280-646b-3b93-0000-000000000000 Thread-1] o.a.n.remote.StandardRemoteProcessGroup Unable to communicate with remote instance RemoteProcessGroup[https://sj46.xxxx:6689/nifi]
org.apache.nifi.controller.exception.CommunicationsException: org.apache.nifi.controller.exception.CommunicationsException: Unable to communicate with Remote NiFi at URI https://sj46.xxxx:6689/nifi due to: Connect to sj46.xxxx:6689 [sj46.xxxx/x.x.x.x] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.nifi.remote.StandardRemoteProcessGroup.refreshFlowContents(StandardRemoteProcessGroup.java:882)
    at org.apache.nifi.remote.StandardRemoteProcessGroup.lambda$initialize$0(StandardRemoteProcessGroup.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.controller.exception.CommunicationsException: Unable to communicate with Remote NiFi at URI https://sj46.xxxx:6689/nifi due to: Connect to sj46.xxxx:6689 [sj46.xxxx/x.x.x.x] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.nifi.remote.StandardRemoteProcessGroup.refreshFlowContents(StandardRemoteProcessGroup.java:844)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Any pointers on how to troubleshoot this issue?

the above issue got resolved by disabling the firewall from MiNiFi server.
now i am getting another issue like below:

```
WARN [Remote Process Group 6bd4b280-646b-3b93-0000-000000000000 Thread-1] o.a.n.r.util.SiteToSiteRestApiClient Failed to get controller from https://sj46.xxxx:6689/nifi-api due to javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
WARN [Remote Process Group 6bd4b280-646b-3b93-0000-000000000000 Thread-1] o.a.n.remote.StandardRemoteProcessGroup Unable to connect to RemoteProcessGroup[https://sj46.xxxx:6689/nifi] due to javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

the above issue of SSLHandshakeException has been resolved by importing the SSl certificate (which you can refer in NiFi.properties especially keystore.jks and truststore.jks) to the MiNiFi. we need to manually modify config.yml in MiNiFi.

after this issue, i was facing the below one:

```
ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.c.t.ContinuallyRunConnectableTask RemoteGroupPort[name=From MiNiFi,targets=https://sj46.xxxx:6689/nifi] failed to process session due to java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;

ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.c.t.ContinuallyRunConnectableTask 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;
```

the SSLContext issue has been resolved by changing the MiNiFi version from 0.4 to 0.3.

Now i am successfully able to fetch data from MiNiFi server to the NiFi.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see that your remote port is configured at 6698.

1. Try to telnet the NiFi Host on 6698 from the machine where MiNiFi is running. Try to see the inbound rules configured on the NiFi Host. (Telnetting to a remote host on a specific port is to check whether you are able to communicate with that host over that specific port. It has got nothing to do with whether the specific port on your machine is open or not. )
2. Add the NiFi Host name in nifi.properties under #Site to Site Properties

   **nifi.remote.input.host=Host where NiFi is running**
3. I would suggest, just to remove the mist of confusion over the common patterns of NiFi Web URL Port and Remote Input Port, try changing this in nifi.properties

   **nifi.remote.input.socket.port=1026**
4. Also add the below section under Input Ports in config.yml:

   **Properties:

           Port: 6698
           Host Name:**

For config.yml and nifi.properties modification references, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299198/minifi-nifi-connection-failure-unknown-host-exception-able-to-telnet-host-f?noredirect=1#comment97500213_53299198).

Comment: i was able to fix the issue by disabling the firewall from MiNiFi server. Now i am getting another issue which you can find above. please help me on this. thanks